# Unable to Google Search Successfully with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a basic google search with Selenium. It's very basic code, but it's still not returning any search results

```
!pip install kora -q
from kora.selenium import wd
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def get_results(search_string): 
  url = 'https://www.google.com/'
  wd.get(url)
  time.sleep(3)
  subject_box = wd.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name=q]')
  subject_box.send_keys('search_string')
  subject_box.submit()
  time.sleep(3)
  html2 = wd.page_source 

  print(html2)

get_results('dog')
```

My output is as follows, I can't find the search term dog anywhere - There's more than this, but you get the point:

Output 1:

[image: Output 1]

Output 2:

[image: Output 2]

Any advice on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subject_box.send_keys('search_string')
```

change to

```
subject_box.send_keys(search_string)
```

you are not passsing the variable instead just a sting 'search_string' , when the quotes removedit will pass the value dog from the varaible instead

Comment: please accept the answer b y pressing the tick sign